# Blogdown website rendering unformatted on github deployment

Tags: web, github, rendering, blogdown

I am a newby to blogdown. I tried to deploy my blogdown website on github, however, I cannot render the website properly. I can see the home page unformatted and when I click on the links to contact and others it says: "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here". My code is at [enter link description here](https://github.com/rubenzunguze/procava). I had to add index.html at the end of this link to get the homepage (unformatted) but the other pages do not even appear.

Anyone has had the same issue? Can anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

You should bypass the default `jekyll` static site generator by creating a file named .nojekyll in the root of your pages repo.

Your repo looks fine.

source: https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/